# listview itemtemplate with an image

Tags: wpf, user-interface, listviewitem

I am trying to create a `ListViewItem` template which looks like [this](http://postimage.org/image/sovqijni9/), but i'm not making much headway.

Here is the style I have created so far:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1.5" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF997137">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4B4B4B" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8F8F8F" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="32" Source="/Images/stop.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" />
                <TextBlock Foreground="#FFECAD25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="150" >
                    This is a user control. The animation uses the attached BalloonShowing event.
                </TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images/Close.png" Stretch="Fill"
                           Opacity="0.4" ToolTip="Delete" x:Name="Delete" />
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16" Height="16" Source="/Images/Close.png" Stretch="Fill"
                           Opacity="0.4" ToolTip="Edit" x:Name="Edit" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Is it possible to extend the text below the image/icon?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any out-of-the box way to do this with a `TextBlock'.

However, if you are able to use the `FlowDocument` control, here are some options: [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339051/wrapping-text-around-an-image-or-linking-two-textblocks-in-c-sharp-wpf), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573199/how-do-you-wrap-text-around-an-image-inside-a-list-box-item-in-wpf).

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, no. Not atleast with simple Image and TextBlock.
FlowDocument seems to be good solution though,
check out this link for further information:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wpf/WPFFlowDocumentsAndImages.aspx